# Finding a congruence chain (linear and quadratic) equivalent to a polynomial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I want to find a congruence chain (linear and quadratic) equivalent to $2x^2+3x-k \equiv 0 (\mod5)$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I've started with considering the polynomial for $x=1,2,3,4$ but I don't know how one can find a congruence chain.

Can someone explain me what it means?

Thanks

Comment: What is *a congruence chain*? I don't recall hearing of such a thing. Ok, I do call things like
$$3^{13}\equiv3^{2\cdot6+1}\equiv(3^6)^2\cdot3^1\equiv1^2\cdot3\equiv3\pmod7$$ congruence chains (here modulo $7$), but that  does not make sense here.

Comment: The text of one exercise call it in this way, probably it's what you mean in the comment